# Can't record my JMeter transactions

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I can't record my chrome actions in Jmeter, because of below mentioned screen shot. Is there any suggestion for this ?

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431788/keytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-external-command . Add your JDK's /bin folder to the PATH environmental variable. You can do this under System settings > Environmental variables, or via CLI:
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin

Comment: @Dmitri Is there any suggestion from you ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `proxy.cert.directory` setting is incorrect, you need to amend the property value to point to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

If for any reason your user account doesn't have permissions to create files in JMeter's "bin" folder - set it to the location, you can create files at. The folder must exist.

`proxy.cert.directory` property can be set in at least 3 ways:

- in *jmeter.properties* file (not recommended)
- in *user.properties* file (recommended for permanent changes)
- via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) (recommended for temporary changes)

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details.