# Conceptual Confusion regarding SSL

Tags: web-services, soap, ssl, coldfusion, wsdl

Please correct me if I'm conceptually wrong:

**Scenario 1:**

I'm using Dreamweaver to access the Coldfusion 8 server which is installed on Windows Server. It's in my local network. I can login into the box using RealVNC.
I have a WSDL opened inside the box, on Internet Explorer. The same WSDL ,when I try to open in my web browser(Firefox or any other), I get the message that the web page
is nto available. I remember, my client who provided me the WSDL asked me about the IP address which he wanted to add in his firewall. I believe this is the reason
why I am unable to acces the WSDL on my desktop ( from where I can VNC into the Windows Server where CF 8 is installed). Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere?

**Scenario 2:**

As mentioned above, I'm basically working on the Windows Server via dreamweaver installed on my computer.I am creating coldfusion files on the Windows server
(via dreamweaver) and trying to send a SOAP request to the WSDL. I'm getting following error:

Unable to read WSDL from URL: `https://testing/abcphp?wsdl.`
Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated.

I know it's an webservice over an SSL proble but my concern is not related with the error here. What I'm thinking is as follows:

Although I'm trying to access and work on coldfusion server via dreamweaver, the error message I'm receiving is on my desktop's browser. So, my questions is, can this be
because of my IP address? I mean my IP address is not the one which the client asked and added to his firewall it's the box IP address which was supplied to the client
as I described in Scenario 1.

So if this is not because of my IP address, then I'm pretty much sure that I need to add the SSL certificate in Coldfusion 8(which is installed on the box) Truststore.

Please confirm that I am not confused here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1**

Yes, absolutely it can be a problem with the server not accepting your ip address. If they have their firewall configured to block you then you cannot get their page. Notice that you are getting `Not Available`, meaning it cannot connect to the server. This may be due to several reasons but them blocking you is one of them. Especially since they apparently told you that they will need to grant you access.

**Scenario 2**

Again, there can be several reasons for this but if the end point is using SSL then you will need their certificate in the keystore for ColdFusion to communicate with the service (to decrypt the packets). Obviously they will also have to allow your ColdFusion server's ip address through their firewall. Notice that you are getting `Peer not authenticated` here. As an aside, you will probably also need user name and password credentials from them. They should really be providing you with all of the information you need to communicate with their service(s).

I have already given you step by step instructions on how to install the SSL certificate for use with ColdFusion under your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449937/1636917

Comment: `SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` is not a username/password issue. It means the client did not get any cert. It's either because no cert was cert or, with some versions of Apache HTTP Client when the server cert isn't trusted (this is normally not the exception for that).

Comment: @Bruno - yes that is what I was trying to say. I was also trying to point out that they may need username and password credentials (partially based on other questions the OP has asked).