# Coldfusion scheduler

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-11

Would like to ask a query regarding coldfusion scheduler.
Our application running on coldfusion 11 was working smoothly for past few years.From may 30,last saturday, the cf schedulers stopped working. From the scheduler log the message received was

> Connection Failure: Status code unavailable

Any  help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The error message is telling you that the http request failed to connect with it's destination. What are the details of your scheduled task? What is it doing?

Comment: Its most likely a certficate/java ketstore issue with http request.

Comment: It is just select insert db query functionality only. All the schedulers are getting same error in scheduler log,they were all working smoothly till last week for past few years. Also, working fine when hit from browser url.                                   Added the certificate and restarted server,still receiving same error. Is there any way to verify/cross check the certificate/java issue?

Comment: Here are the steps to install and verify the certificate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449937/1636917